# Java JTable Default table model cell edit and column size

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem in my code that when using cell edit not allowed then the column size does not work properly

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

public class cTable extends JPanel {

private final int keyIndex;
private final int keyIncrement;
private ArrayList<String> tHeaderTitle;
private ArrayList<Integer> tHeaderWidth;

DefaultTableModel dataModel = new DefaultTableModel() {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int mColIndex) {
        return false;
    }
};

JTable table = new JTable(dataModel);

public cTable(ArrayList<String> THeaderTitle, ArrayList< Integer>    THeaderWidth, int KeyIndex, int KeyIncrement) {

    if (THeaderTitle.isEmpty()) {
        tHeaderTitle.add("Title1");
    } else {
        tHeaderTitle = new ArrayList<>(THeaderTitle);
    }

    if (THeaderWidth.isEmpty()) {
        tHeaderWidth.add(30);
    } else {
        tHeaderWidth = new ArrayList<>(THeaderWidth);
    }

    keyIndex = KeyIndex;
    keyIncrement = KeyIncrement;

    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    table.setAutoscrolls(true);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    scrollPane.setAutoscrolls(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < tHeaderTitle.size(); i++) {
        dataModel.addColumn(tHeaderTitle.get(i));
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(tHeaderWidth.get(i));
    }

    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(TotalWidth(tHeaderWidth) + 110, 100));
    table.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
    table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    table.setRowHeight(25);

    add(scrollPane);
}

public void addColumn(String cName, int cWidth) {

    dataModel.addColumn(cName);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(dataModel.getColumnCount() - 1).setPreferredWidth(cWidth);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(TotalWidth(tHeaderWidth) + cWidth, 150));
    tHeaderWidth.add(cWidth);
}

public void addRow(String[] values) {
    boolean exists = false;
    if (dataModel.getRowCount() == 0) {
        dataModel.addRow(values);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
            if (dataModel.getValueAt(i, keyIndex) == values[keyIndex]) {
                 dataModel.setValueAt(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(dataModel.getValueAt(i,  keyIncrement))) + 1, i, keyIncrement);
                exists = true;
            }
        }
        if (!exists) {
            dataModel.addRow(values);
        }

    }
 }

 private int TotalWidth(ArrayList<Integer> wl) {
     int sum = 0;
     for (Integer wl1 : wl) {
         sum += wl1;
     }
     return sum;
 }
 }
```

and in my main frame class mainClass I used the cTable component to create my customized table but the column size does not appear to be right , actually it does not work and the cells should be editable

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
........
public class mainClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
......
// initialize frame settings to add a cTable component
......

ArrayList<Integer> TheaderWidth = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> TheaderTitle = new ArrayList<>();
cTable InvTable;
TheaderTitle.add("id");
TheaderTitle.add("Qty");
TheaderTitle.add("Description");
TheaderTitle.add("Notes");
TheaderWidth.add(30);
TheaderWidth.add(50);
TheaderWidth.add(200);
TheaderWidth.add(100);
InvTable = new cTable(TheaderTitle, TheaderWidth, 1, 2);
InvTable.setBounds(10, 10, 600, 300);
panel1.add(InvTable);
InvTable.setVisible(true);
this.pack();
}
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character!